# how can i use python's like "For loop" in php to reverse string?

Tags: php, python, loops

Here is python code:

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    return revers(s) == s

def revers(s):
    ret = ''
    for ch in s:
        ret = ch + ret
    return ret

print is_palindrome('RACECAR') 
# that will print true
```

when i convert that function to php.

```
function is_palindrome($string){
    if (strrev($string) == $string) return true;
    return false;
}
$word = "RACECAR";
var_dump(is_palindrome($word));
// true
```

Both functions works fine but, how can i revers string with php in loop ??

```
$string = str_split(hello);
$output = '';
foreach($string as $c){
        $output .= $c;
}
print $output;
// output 
hello 
//i did this,
```

that's work find but is there any way to do that in better way ?
    $string = "hello";
    $lent   = strlen($string);

```
$ret = '';
for($i = $lent; ($i > 0) or ($i == 0); $i--)
{
    $ret .= $string[$i];
    #$lent = $lent - 1;
}

print $output;
//output 
olleh
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
$output .= $c;
```

with

```
$output = $c . $output;
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't be shorter I guess. With a loop :)

```
$word = "Hello";

$result = '';
foreach($word as $letter)
    $result = $letter . $result;

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't try that code, but I think that it should work:

```
$string = "hello";
$output = "";
$arr = array_reverse(str_split($string)); // Transform "" to [] and then reverse => ["o","l","l,"e","h"]
foreach($arr as $char) {
    $output .= $char;
}

echo $output;
```

Another way:

```
$string = "hello";
$output = "";
for($i = strlen($string); $i >= 0; $i--) {
    $output .= substr($string, $i, 1);
}
echo $output;
```

Answer (score -1):

strrev() is a function that reverses a string in PHP.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php

```
$s = "foobar";
echo strrev($s); //raboof
```

If you want to check if a word is a palindrome:

```
function is_palindrome($word){ return strrev($word) == $word }

$s = "RACECAR";
echo $s." is ".((is_palindrome($s))?"":"NOT ")."a palindrome";
```

Comment: Your question was how to reverse a string in PHP.

Comment: Why would you want to use a loop? It is not needed to check if a string is a palindrome.